# How do I open multiple image files at once using regex (or regex-like) expressions in the Mac OSX command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a directory with many, many files in it. Let's say I want to open these three files:

- IMG_1394.PNG
- IMG_1395.PNG
- IMG_1396.PNG

I know that if I want to open all PNG files, I could use `open *.png`. However, I want to only open these three files. Trying something like

`open IMG_139[4-6].png`

...does not work, nor does

`open IMG_139*.png` (even though that would open more files than I want).

Comment: does `for f in IMG_139[4-6].png; do open $f; done` work?

Comment: That gives me `The file /Users/fitvalet/Downloads/IMG_139[4-6].png does not exist.` (same error)

Comment: And those file *do* exist?

Comment: Legit question - yes double-checked again and yes they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to find the correct files using the `find` command's `-regex` option (`man find`). Then I can pass those files to the `open` command using `xargs`:

```
find . -regex "./IMG_139[4-6]\.PNG" | xargs open
```